# Openshift application not updating after push

Tags: php, wordpress, git, caching, openshift

I'm editing my Wordpress application and making the commit and push to server.

But, I noticed that the updates were not being made. So, i edited index.php file from the SFTP, adding a `die('test')` function and it's not worked.

So, i tried restart my application at panel and then worked in first execution. After not work anymore, only if I restart the application again.

Have any type of cache on Openshift aplications hosted at www.openshift.com / HedHat ?

Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Just disable `hot_deploy` hook to work.

Updates only work if you restart the application. Disabling hot_deploy, the application will restart automaticaly.

If you don't know what's hot_deploy, can get more details bellow:

https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202187274-How-can-I-deploy-my-application-without-having-to-restart-it-